# How to decode huffman code quickly?

Tags: c++, decode, huffman-code

I have implementated [a simple compressor](http://code.google.com/p/jcyangs-alg-trunk/source/browse/trunk/bk/APIDSAA/ch5_binary_tree/Huffman/wHuffmanApp.cc) using pure huffman code under Windows.But I do not know much about how to decode the compressed file quickly,my bad algorithm is:

Enumerate all the huffman code in the code table then compare it with the bits in the compressed file.It turns out horrible result:decompressing 3MB file would need 6 hours.

Could you provide a much more efficient algorithm?Should I use Hash or something?

**Update**:
I have implementated [the decoder](http://code.google.com/p/jcyangs-alg-trunk/source/browse/trunk/bk/APIDSAA/ch5_binary_tree/Huffman/DecodeHuffmanTree.h) with state table,based on my friend Lin's advice.I think this method should be better than travesal huffman tree,3MB within 6s.

thanks.

Comment: Congratulations for your well formatted code. Makes WinAPI code almost palatable.

Comment: FYI: state of the art decoders can do ~1GB/sec (or more) decompression speeds on a current average PC: you must limit the length of huffman codes to 11/12, use decompression table, and use multiple huffman streams, so data dependency is minimized.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way to optimise the binary-tree approach is to use a lookup table. You arrange the table so that you can look up a particular encoded bit-pattern directly, allowing for the maximum possible bit-width of any code.

Since most codes don't use the full maximum width, they are included at multiple locations in the table - one location for each combination of the unused bits. The table indicates how many bits to discard from the input as well as the decoded output.

If the longest code is too long, so the table is impractical, a compromise is to use a tree of smaller fixed-width-subscript lookups. For example, you can use a 256-item table to handle a byte. If the input code is more than 8 bits, the table entry indicates that decoding is incomplete and directs you to a table that handles the next up-to 8 bits. Larger tables trade memory for speed - 256 items is probably too small.

I believe this general approach is called "prefix tables", and is what BobMcGees quoted code is doing. A likely difference is that some compression algorithms require the prefix table to be updated during decompression - this is not needed for simple Huffman. IIRC, I first saw it in a book about bitmapped graphics file formats which included GIF, some time before the patent panic.

It should be easy to precalculate either a full lookup table, a hashtable equivalent, or a tree-of-small-tables from a binary tree model. The binary tree is still the key representation (mental model) of how the code works - this lookup table is just an optimised way to implement it.

Comment: +1 This is the method I used in my JPEG decoder, I build the lookup table directly from the DHT segment in the image, no binary-tree hassles needed.

Answer (score 6):

Why not take a look at how the [GZIP source](http://www.gzip.org/#sources) does it, specifically the Huffman decompression code in specifically unpack.c?  It's doing exactly what you are, except it's doing it much, much faster.

From what I can tell, it's using a lookup array and shift/mask operations operating on whole words to run faster.  Pretty dense code though.

EDIT: here is the complete source

```
/* unpack.c -- decompress files in pack format.
 * Copyright (C) 1992-1993 Jean-loup Gailly
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
 * terms of the GNU General Public License, see the file COPYING.
 */

#ifdef RCSID
static char rcsid[] = "$Id: unpack.c,v 1.4 1993/06/11 19:25:36 jloup Exp $";
#endif

#include "tailor.h"
#include "gzip.h"
#include "crypt.h"

#define MIN(a,b) ((a) <= (b) ? (a) : (b))
/* The arguments must not have side effects. */

#define MAX_BITLEN 25
/* Maximum length of Huffman codes. (Minor modifications to the code
 * would be needed to support 32 bits codes, but pack never generates
 * more than 24 bits anyway.)
 */

#define LITERALS 256
/* Number of literals, excluding the End of Block (EOB) code */

#define MAX_PEEK 12
/* Maximum number of 'peek' bits used to optimize traversal of the
 * Huffman tree.
 */

local ulg orig_len;       /* original uncompressed length */
local int max_len;        /* maximum bit length of Huffman codes */

local uch literal[LITERALS];
/* The literal bytes present in the Huffman tree. The EOB code is not
 * represented.
 */

local int lit_base[MAX_BITLEN+1];
/* All literals of a given bit length are contiguous in literal[] and
 * have contiguous codes. literal[code+lit_base[len]] is the literal
 * for a code of len bits.
 */

local int leaves [MAX_BITLEN+1]; /* Number of leaves for each bit length */
local int parents[MAX_BITLEN+1]; /* Number of parents for each bit length */

local int peek_bits; /* Number of peek bits currently used */

/* local uch prefix_len[1 << MAX_PEEK]; */
#define prefix_len outbuf
/* For each bit pattern b of peek_bits bits, prefix_len[b] is the length
 * of the Huffman code starting with a prefix of b (upper bits), or 0
 * if all codes of prefix b have more than peek_bits bits. It is not
 * necessary to have a huge table (large MAX_PEEK) because most of the
 * codes encountered in the input stream are short codes (by construction).
 * So for most codes a single lookup will be necessary.
 */
#if (1<<MAX_PEEK) > OUTBUFSIZ
    error cannot overlay prefix_len and outbuf
#endif

local ulg bitbuf;
/* Bits are added on the low part of bitbuf and read from the high part. */

local int valid;                  /* number of valid bits in bitbuf */
/* all bits above the last valid bit are always zero */

/* Set code to the next 'bits' input bits without skipping them. code
 * must be the name of a simple variable and bits must not have side effects.
 * IN assertions: bits <= 25 (so that we still have room for an extra byte
 * when valid is only 24), and mask = (1<<bits)-1.
 */
#define look_bits(code,bits,mask) \
{ \
  while (valid < (bits)) bitbuf = (bitbuf<<8) | (ulg)get_byte(), valid += 8; \
  code = (bitbuf >> (valid-(bits))) & (mask); \
}

/* Skip the given number of bits (after having peeked at them): */
#define skip_bits(bits)  (valid -= (bits))

#define clear_bitbuf() (valid = 0, bitbuf = 0)

/* Local functions */

local void read_tree  OF((void));
local void build_tree OF((void));

/* ===========================================================================
 * Read the Huffman tree.
 */
local void read_tree()
{
    int len;  /* bit length */
    int base; /* base offset for a sequence of leaves */
    int n;

    /* Read the original input size, MSB first */
    orig_len = 0;
    for (n = 1; n <= 4; n++) orig_len = (orig_len << 8) | (ulg)get_byte();

    max_len = (int)get_byte(); /* maximum bit length of Huffman codes */
    if (max_len > MAX_BITLEN) {
    error("invalid compressed data -- Huffman code > 32 bits");
    }

    /* Get the number of leaves at each bit length */
    n = 0;
    for (len = 1; len <= max_len; len++) {
    leaves[len] = (int)get_byte();
    n += leaves[len];
    }
    if (n > LITERALS) {
    error("too many leaves in Huffman tree");
    }
    Trace((stderr, "orig_len %ld, max_len %d, leaves %d\n",
       orig_len, max_len, n));
    /* There are at least 2 and at most 256 leaves of length max_len.
     * (Pack arbitrarily rejects empty files and files consisting of
     * a single byte even repeated.) To fit the last leaf count in a
     * byte, it is offset by 2. However, the last literal is the EOB
     * code, and is not transmitted explicitly in the tree, so we must
     * adjust here by one only.
     */
    leaves[max_len]++;

    /* Now read the leaves themselves */
    base = 0;
    for (len = 1; len <= max_len; len++) {
    /* Remember where the literals of this length start in literal[] : */
    lit_base[len] = base;
    /* And read the literals: */
    for (n = leaves[len]; n > 0; n--) {
        literal[base++] = (uch)get_byte();
    }
    }
    leaves[max_len]++; /* Now include the EOB code in the Huffman tree */
}

/* ===========================================================================
 * Build the Huffman tree and the prefix table.
 */
local void build_tree()
{
    int nodes = 0; /* number of nodes (parents+leaves) at current bit length */
    int len;       /* current bit length */
    uch *prefixp;  /* pointer in prefix_len */

    for (len = max_len; len >= 1; len--) {
    /* The number of parent nodes at this level is half the total
     * number of nodes at parent level:
     */
    nodes >>= 1;
    parents[len] = nodes;
    /* Update lit_base by the appropriate bias to skip the parent nodes
     * (which are not represented in the literal array):
     */
    lit_base[len] -= nodes;
    /* Restore nodes to be parents+leaves: */
    nodes += leaves[len];
    }
    /* Construct the prefix table, from shortest leaves to longest ones.
     * The shortest code is all ones, so we start at the end of the table.
     */
    peek_bits = MIN(max_len, MAX_PEEK);
    prefixp = &prefix_len[1<<peek_bits];
    for (len = 1; len <= peek_bits; len++) {
    int prefixes = leaves[len] << (peek_bits-len); /* may be 0 */
    while (prefixes--) *--prefixp = (uch)len;
    }
    /* The length of all other codes is unknown: */
    while (prefixp > prefix_len) *--prefixp = 0;
}

/* ===========================================================================
 * Unpack in to out.  This routine does not support the old pack format
 * with magic header \037\037.
 *
 * IN assertions: the buffer inbuf contains already the beginning of
 *   the compressed data, from offsets inptr to insize-1 included.
 *   The magic header has already been checked. The output buffer is cleared.
 */
int unpack(in, out)
    int in, out;            /* input and output file descriptors */
{
    int len;                /* Bit length of current code */
    unsigned eob;           /* End Of Block code */
    register unsigned peek; /* lookahead bits */
    unsigned peek_mask;     /* Mask for peek_bits bits */

    ifd = in;
    ofd = out;

    read_tree();     /* Read the Huffman tree */
    build_tree();    /* Build the prefix table */
    clear_bitbuf();  /* Initialize bit input */
    peek_mask = (1<<peek_bits)-1;

    /* The eob code is the largest code among all leaves of maximal length: */
    eob = leaves[max_len]-1;
    Trace((stderr, "eob %d %x\n", max_len, eob));

    /* Decode the input data: */
    for (;;) {
    /* Since eob is the longest code and not shorter than max_len,
         * we can peek at max_len bits without having the risk of reading
         * beyond the end of file.
     */
    look_bits(peek, peek_bits, peek_mask);
    len = prefix_len[peek];
    if (len > 0) {
        peek >>= peek_bits - len; /* discard the extra bits */
    } else {
        /* Code of more than peek_bits bits, we must traverse the tree */
        ulg mask = peek_mask;
        len = peek_bits;
        do {
                len++, mask = (mask<<1)+1;
        look_bits(peek, len, mask);
        } while (peek < (unsigned)parents[len]);
        /* loop as long as peek is a parent node */
    }
    /* At this point, peek is the next complete code, of len bits */
    if (peek == eob && len == max_len) break; /* end of file? */
    put_ubyte(literal[peek+lit_base[len]]);
    Tracev((stderr,"%02d %04x %c\n", len, peek,
        literal[peek+lit_base[len]]));
    skip_bits(len);
    } /* for (;;) */

    flush_window();
    Trace((stderr, "bytes_out %ld\n", bytes_out));
    if (orig_len != (ulg)bytes_out) {
    error("invalid compressed data--length error");
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to decompress a Huffman code is using a binary tree. You insert your codes in the tree, so that each bit in a code represents a branch either to the left (0) or right (1), with decoded bytes (or whatever values you have) in the leaves.

Decoding is then just a case of reading bits from the coded content, walking the tree for each bit. When you reach a leaf, emit that decoded value, and keep reading until the input is exhausted.

**Update:** [this page](http://www.arturocampos.com/cp_ch3-3.html) describes the technique, and has fancy graphics.

Comment: A linked structure is most useful for constructing the tree, but I would think that an array would be best for performing the lookup. It doesn't have to be completely populated, but 16-bit keys into a 65536 node array should perform just fine. NB: I haven't ever written a decompressor.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: So, how do you go from a buffer holding varying-length (at the bit-level) Huffman codes, to an array index? The point of the tree-based approach is that it tells you when to stop reading bits. Maybe I'm just missing something, it's been a while since I wrote a Huffman decoder.

Comment: @unwind: you can read several bits at once and use a lookup table containing either branch nodes or leaf nodes. Branch nodes give a pointer to the table for the next few bits. Leaf nodes give the decoded value, and the actual length so you know how many extra bits you read. If there's a reasonable maximum length (say 16 bits or less) then you can use a single table of leaf nodes as Potatoswatter suggests.

Comment: @Mike: Sure, I guess ... But to handle codes shorter than 8 bits, it would of course still need to do bit-level reads from the input, and deal with that.

Comment: Typically, you'll read the input a word at a time into a variable, logically AND it with a mask to read the next few bits, and right-shift it once you've finished with those bits (keeping track of how many valid bits are left). Plus a bit of work each time you cross a word boundary. It's more code than reading a bit at a time, but can be significantly faster.

Comment: @unwind:I gave a thought to binary tree before,but it seems to me that it is not much efficient,it is something like regular expression matcher,but here the leaf is the final state :)

Comment: What you do is just filling up the lookup table with all combinations that come along with it. So having only 3bits in a four bit table for the letter A you find A for all potential combinations of additional bits (010 - Code, 0100 = A, 0101 = A). You use two tables one for the symbol (or the next lookup table to use) and a second for the number of bits actually use. Therefor 0100 = (A,3), 0101 = (A,3). This way no AND operation is needed.

Comment: A 2 level table lookup is implemented in C++ as utility classes here: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalHuffman

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a kind of batch lookup on the usual Huffmann tree lookup:

1. Choosing a bit depth (call it depth *n*); this is a trade-off between speed, memory, and time investment to construct tables;
2. Build a lookup table for all 2^*n* bit strings of length *n*.  Each entry may encode several complete tokens; there will commonly also be some bits left over that are only a prefix of Huffman codes: for each of these, make a link to a further lookup table for that code;
3. Build the further lookup tables.  The total number of tables is at most one less than the number of entries coded in the Huffmann tree.

Choosing a depth that is a multiple of four, e.g., depth 8, is a good fit for bit shifting operations.

**Postscript**  This differs from the idea in potatoswatter's comment on unwind's answer and from Steve314's answer in using multiple tables: this means that all of the *n*-bit lookup is put to use, so should be faster but makes table construction and lookup significantly trickier, and will consume much more space for a given depth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the decompress algorithm in the same source module?  It appears to be a decent algorithm.

Comment: Isn't that the decompressor that the OP says will take 6 hours to decompress the 3MB file?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right, but here is some code in Rust I wrote recently to make the ideas concrete. This is the key routine:

```
  fn decode( &self, input: &mut InpBitStream ) -> usize
  {
    let mut sym = self.lookup[ input.peek( self.peekbits ) ];
    if sym >= self.ncode
    {
      sym = self.lookup[ sym - self.ncode + ( input.peek( self.maxbits ) >> self.peekbits ) ];
    }  
    input.advance( self.nbits[ sym ] as usize );
    sym
  }
```

The tricky bit is setting up the lookup table, see BitDecoder::setup_code in this complete RFC 1951 decoder in Rust:

```
// RFC 1951 inflate ( de-compress ).

pub fn inflate( data: &[u8] ) -> Vec<u8>
{
  let mut inp = InpBitStream::new( &data );
  let mut out = Vec::new();
  let _chk = inp.get_bits( 16 ); // Checksum
  loop
  {
    let last = inp.get_bit();
    let btype = inp.get_bits( 2 );
    match btype
    {
      2 => { do_dyn( &mut inp, &mut out ); }
      1 => { do_fixed( &mut inp, &mut out ); }
      0 => { do_copy( &mut inp, &mut out ); }
      _ => { }
    }
    if last != 0 { break; }
  }  
  out
}

fn do_dyn( inp: &mut InpBitStream, out: &mut Vec<u8> )
{
  let n_lit_code = 257 + inp.get_bits( 5 );
  let n_dist_code = 1 + inp.get_bits( 5 );
  let n_len_code = 4 + inp.get_bits( 4 );

  let mut len = LenDecoder::new( inp, n_len_code );

  let mut lit = BitDecoder::new( n_lit_code );
  len.get_lengths( inp, &mut lit.nbits );
  lit.init(); 

  let mut dist = BitDecoder::new( n_dist_code );
  len.get_lengths( inp, &mut dist.nbits );
  dist.init();

  loop
  {
    let x = lit.decode( inp );
    match x
    {
      0..=255 => { out.push( x as u8 ); }
      256 =>  { break; } 
      _ =>
      {
        let mc = x - 257;
        let length = MATCH_OFF[ mc ] + inp.get_bits( MATCH_EXTRA[ mc ] as usize );
        let dc = dist.decode( inp );
        let distance = DIST_OFF[ dc ] + inp.get_bits( DIST_EXTRA[ dc ] as usize );
        copy( out, distance, length ); 
      }
    }
  }
} // end do_dyn

fn copy( out: &mut Vec<u8>, distance: usize, mut length: usize )
{
  let mut i = out.len() - distance;
  while length > 0
  {
    out.push( out[ i ] );
    i += 1;
    length -= 1;
  }
}

/// Decode length-limited Huffman codes.
struct BitDecoder
{
  ncode: usize,
  nbits: Vec<u8>,
  maxbits: usize,
  peekbits: usize,
  lookup: Vec<usize>
}

impl BitDecoder
{
  fn new( ncode: usize ) -> BitDecoder
  {
    BitDecoder 
    { 
      ncode,
      nbits: vec![0; ncode],
      maxbits: 0,
      peekbits: 0,
      lookup: Vec::new()
    }
  }

  /// The key routine, will be called many times.
  fn decode( &self, input: &mut InpBitStream ) -> usize
  {
    let mut sym = self.lookup[ input.peek( self.peekbits ) ];
    if sym >= self.ncode
    {
      sym = self.lookup[ sym - self.ncode + ( input.peek( self.maxbits ) >> self.peekbits ) ];
    }  
    input.advance( self.nbits[ sym ] as usize );
    sym
  }

  fn init( &mut self )
  {
    let ncode = self.ncode;

    let mut max_bits : usize = 0; 
    for bp in &self.nbits 
    { 
      let bits = *bp as usize;
      if bits > max_bits { max_bits = bits; } 
    }

    self.maxbits = max_bits;
    self.peekbits = if max_bits > 8 { 8 } else { max_bits };
    self.lookup.resize( 1 << self.peekbits, 0 );

    // Code below is from rfc1951 page 7

    let mut bl_count : Vec<usize> = vec![ 0; max_bits + 1 ]; // the number of codes of length N, N >= 1.

    for i in 0..ncode { bl_count[ self.nbits[i] as usize ] += 1; }

    let mut next_code : Vec<usize> = vec![ 0; max_bits + 1 ];
    let mut code = 0; 
    bl_count[0] = 0;

    for i in 0..max_bits
    {
      code = ( code + bl_count[i] ) << 1;
      next_code[ i + 1 ] = code;
    }

    for i in 0..ncode
    {
      let len = self.nbits[ i ] as usize;
      if len != 0
      {
        self.setup_code( i, len, next_code[ len ] );
        next_code[ len ] += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  // Decoding is done using self.lookup ( see decode ). To keep the lookup table small,
  // codes longer than 8 bits are looked up in two peeks.

  fn setup_code( &mut self, sym: usize, len: usize, mut code: usize )
  {
    if len <= self.peekbits
    {
      let diff = self.peekbits - len;
      for i in code << diff .. (code << diff) + (1 << diff)
      {
        // bits are reversed to match InpBitStream::peek
        let r = reverse( i, self.peekbits );
        self.lookup[ r ] = sym;
      }
    } else {
      // Secondary lookup required.
      let peekbits2 = self.maxbits - self.peekbits;

      // Split code into peekbits portion ( key ) and remainder ( code).
      let diff1 = len - self.peekbits;
      let key = code >> diff1;
      code &= ( 1 << diff1 ) - 1;

      // Get the secondary lookup.
      let kr = reverse( key, self.peekbits );
      let mut base = self.lookup[ kr ];
      if base == 0 // Secondary lookup not yet allocated for this key.
      {
        base = self.lookup.len();
        self.lookup.resize( base + ( 1 << peekbits2 ), 0 );
        self.lookup[ kr ] = self.ncode + base;
      } else {
        base -= self.ncode;
      }

      // Set the secondary lookup values.
      let diff = self.maxbits - len;
      for i in code << diff .. (code << diff) + (1<<diff)
      { 
        let r = reverse( i, peekbits2 );
        self.lookup[ base + r ] = sym;
      }
    }    
  }
} // end impl BitDecoder

struct InpBitStream<'a>
{
  data: &'a [u8],
  pos: usize,
  buf: usize,
  got: usize, // Number of bits in buffer.
}

impl <'a> InpBitStream<'a>
{
  fn new( data: &'a [u8] ) -> InpBitStream
  {
    InpBitStream { data, pos: 0, buf: 1, got: 0 }
  } 

  fn peek( &mut self, n: usize ) -> usize
  {
    while self.got < n
    {
      if self.pos < self.data.len() 
      {
        self.buf |= ( self.data[ self.pos ] as usize ) << self.got;
      }
      self.pos += 1;
      self.got += 8;
    }
    self.buf & ( ( 1 << n ) - 1 )
  }

  fn advance( &mut self, n:usize )
  { 
    self.buf >>= n;
    self.got -= n;
  }

  fn get_bit( &mut self ) -> usize
  {
    if self.got == 0 { self.peek( 1 ); }
    let result = self.buf & 1;
    self.advance( 1 );
    result
  }

  fn get_bits( &mut self, n: usize ) -> usize
  { 
    let result = self.peek( n );
    self.advance( n );
    result
  }

  fn get_huff( &mut self, mut n: usize ) -> usize 
  { 
    let mut result = 0; 
    while n > 0
    { 
      result = ( result << 1 ) + self.get_bit(); 
      n -= 1;
    }
    result
  }

  fn clear_bits( &mut self )
  {
    self.got = 0;
  }
} //  end impl InpBitStream

/// Decode code lengths.
struct LenDecoder
{
  plenc: u8, // previous length code ( which can be repeated )
  rep: usize,   // repeat
  bd: BitDecoder,
}

/// Decodes an array of lengths. There are special codes for repeats, and repeats of zeros.
impl LenDecoder
{
  fn new( inp: &mut InpBitStream, n_len_code: usize ) -> LenDecoder
  {
    let mut result = LenDecoder { plenc: 0, rep:0, bd: BitDecoder::new( 19 ) };

    // Read the array of 3-bit code lengths from input.
    for i in 0..n_len_code 
    { 
      result.bd.nbits[ CLEN_ALPHABET[i] as usize ] = inp.get_bits(3) as u8; 
    }
    result.bd.init();
    result
  }

  // Per RFC1931 page 13, get array of code lengths.
  fn get_lengths( &mut self, inp: &mut InpBitStream, result: &mut Vec<u8> )
  {
    let n = result.len();
    let mut i = 0;
    while self.rep > 0 { result[i] = self.plenc; i += 1; self.rep -= 1; }
    while i < n
    { 
      let lenc = self.bd.decode( inp ) as u8;
      if lenc < 16 
      {
        result[i] = lenc; 
        i += 1; 
        self.plenc = lenc; 
      } else {
        if lenc == 16 { self.rep = 3 + inp.get_bits(2); }
        else if lenc == 17 { self.rep = 3 + inp.get_bits(3); self.plenc=0; }
        else if lenc == 18 { self.rep = 11 + inp.get_bits(7); self.plenc=0; } 
        while i < n && self.rep > 0 { result[i] = self.plenc; i += 1; self.rep -= 1; }
      }
    }
  } // end get_lengths
} // end impl LenDecoder

/// Reverse a string of bits.
pub fn reverse( mut x:usize, mut bits: usize ) -> usize
{ 
  let mut result: usize = 0; 
  while bits > 0
  {
    result = ( result << 1 ) | ( x & 1 ); 
    x >>= 1; 
    bits -= 1;
  } 
  result
} 

fn do_copy( inp: &mut InpBitStream, out: &mut Vec<u8> )
{
  inp.clear_bits(); // Discard any bits in the input buffer
  let mut n = inp.get_bits( 16 );
  let _n1 = inp.get_bits( 16 );
  while n > 0 { out.push( inp.data[ inp.pos ] ); n -= 1; inp.pos += 1; }
}

fn do_fixed( inp: &mut InpBitStream, out: &mut Vec<u8> ) // RFC1951 page 12.
{
  loop
  {
    // 0 to 23 ( 7 bits ) => 256 - 279; 48 - 191 ( 8 bits ) => 0 - 143; 
    // 192 - 199 ( 8 bits ) => 280 - 287; 400..511 ( 9 bits ) => 144 - 255
    let mut x = inp.get_huff( 7 ); 
    if x <= 23 
    { 
      x += 256; 
    } else {
      x = ( x << 1 ) + inp.get_bit();
      if x <= 191 { x -= 48; }
      else if x <= 199 { x += 88; }
      else { x = ( x << 1 ) + inp.get_bit() - 256; }
    }

    match x
    {
      0..=255 => { out.push( x as u8 ); }
      256 => { break; } 
      _ => // 257 <= x && x <= 285 
      { 
        x -= 257;
        let length = MATCH_OFF[x] + inp.get_bits( MATCH_EXTRA[ x ] as usize );
        let dcode = inp.get_huff( 5 );
        let distance = DIST_OFF[dcode] + inp.get_bits( DIST_EXTRA[dcode] as usize );
        copy( out, distance, length );
      }
    }
  }
} // end do_fixed

// RFC 1951 constants.

pub static CLEN_ALPHABET : [u8; 19] = [ 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15 ];

pub static MATCH_OFF : [usize; 30] = [ 3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10, 11,13,15,17, 19,23,27,31, 35,43,51,59, 
  67,83,99,115,  131,163,195,227, 258, 0xffff ];

pub static MATCH_EXTRA : [u8; 29] = [ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 0 ];

pub static DIST_OFF : [usize; 30] = [ 1,2,3,4, 5,7,9,13, 17,25,33,49, 65,97,129,193, 257,385,513,769, 
  1025,1537,2049,3073, 4097,6145,8193,12289, 16385,24577 ];

pub static DIST_EXTRA : [u8; 30] = [ 0,0,0,0, 1,1,2,2, 3,3,4,4, 5,5,6,6, 7,7,8,8, 9,9,10,10, 11,11,12,12, 13,13 ];
```

[Github repository here](https://github.com/georgebarwood/Rust/blob/master/inflate.rs)